# How to run tests by testname in TestNG with maven

Tags: java, maven, testing

I have a maven project, which uses surefire and testng to run automation scripts,
my testng looks like this:

```
<suite name="Suite1">
<test name="foo">
    <parameter name="var" value="${env.name}"/>
    <packages>
        <package name="main.java.automation_scripts.tests"/>
    </packages>
</test>

<test name="bar">
    <classes>
        <class name="main.java.automation_scripts.bar_tests.test.java"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

When fire command

```
mvn clean test -Denv.name=name -Dtestnames="bar" -DsuiteXmlFile=TestNG.xml
```

it executes all tests in `Suite1`,  I want only those specified by argument to be run, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried with "testclass" property - By specifying the test name

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: mvn test -Dtest=classname : instead of giving testnames, you can try this